# List not appending properly when passed to function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with list of lists, that the list loses sub-lists' values.
When I pass the list to function, the function operates on the list and then the list is returned but sub-lists of the list are empty.

```
def solve_n_queens(size):
    possible_places = []
    solve_n_queens_helper(0, size, [], possible_places)
    return possible_places


def solve_n_queens_helper(row, size, curr_placings, possible_places):
    if row == size:
        possible_places.append(curr_placings)
        print(possible_places) # here it prints list of sublists correctly

    for col in range(size):
        cell = (row, col)
        if is_valid_with_previous(cell, curr_placings):
            curr_placings.append(cell)
            solve_n_queens_helper(row + 1, size, curr_placings, possible_places)
            curr_placings.pop()


def is_valid_with_previous(queen_position, prev_queen_positions):
    for prev_queen_position in prev_queen_positions:
        if prev_queen_position[1] == queen_position[1]:
            return False

        row_distance = abs(prev_queen_position[0] - queen_position[0])
        col_distance = abs(prev_queen_position[1] - queen_position[1])

        if row_distance == 0 or row_distance == col_distance:
            return False

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(solve_n_queens(4))
```

It should return `[[(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 3), (3, 1)], [(0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 3), (3, 1)]]` but it returns `[[], []]`. When I print `possible_placings` while the algorithm is running it prints the list correctly, the values are in the sub-lists, but when algorithm terminates, the values disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you add `curr_placings` to the result list, but then `pop` each of the elements from those lists. Create a copy when adding the results:

```
if row == size:
    possible_places.append(list(curr_placings))  # <-- copy list!
    print(possible_places)
```

Alternatively, `curr_placings[:]` or `curr_placings.copy()` would also work. The same would also be necessary if you used `yield` or `return` instead of collecting the solutions in a list.